# Unable to find linux Kernel Headers

Tags: linux-kernel

I am running a custom kernel(I am not the creator of it). I need the header files for the same. .

I have tried installing the header files using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

But it failed to find the header.

Also  have tried looking into /usr/src/ for the header,and it is not there.

Is there a method to obtain header files for custom kernels?

Comment: What distro and version? Where did you obtain the kernel package from?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:** Check if the custom kernel included the source code.

**Approach 2:** Contact the creator.

**Approach 3:** Try similar headers if included in the repository.  This approach may cause issues or may work.

To list all linux headers in the repository: `apt list 'linux-headers*'`

Use `uname -r` to get the kernel release.

**Approach 4:** Download original source for that release from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel.

Comment: Thank you. Have tried Approach 3. Can you elaborate on Approach 1. Because the source of the code is available on github.